# How can i stream my screen over another virtual machine in cloud using python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ngrok, tunneling

I am trying to capture gameplay over my computer and wants the live captured gameplay to be sent to my cloud instance for the purpose of object detection.
I have tried the following code.It works well locally but when I tunnel it using ngrok I am getting
getaddress error.

Is there any other way which I can send the video frames at good FPS over the internet to my cloud instance for performing deep learning processing on it?

client.py

```
import cv2
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import pickle
import zlib

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#client_socket.connect(('localhost', 8485))
#Tring to connect to the hosted address obtained after using ngrok http 8485 command.
client_socket.connect(('https://fc766cc3.ngrok.io',0)) 
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cam.set(3, 320);
cam.set(4, 240);

img_counter = 0

encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
#    data = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(frame, 0))
    data = pickle.dumps(frame, 0)
    size = len(data)


    print("{}: {}".format(img_counter, size))
    client_socket.sendall(struct.pack(">L", size) + data)
    img_counter += 1

cam.release()
```

server.py

```
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
import struct ## new
import zlib

HOST='localhost'
PORT=8485

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

s.bind((HOST,PORT))
print('Socket bind complete')
s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn,addr=s.accept()

data = b""
payload_size = struct.calcsize(">L")
print("payload_size: {}".format(payload_size))
while True:
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        print("Recv: {}".format(len(data)))
        data += conn.recv(4096)

    print("Done Recv: {}".format(len(data)))
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack(">L", packed_msg_size)[0]
    print("msg_size: {}".format(msg_size))
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]

    frame=pickle.loads(frame_data, fix_imports=True, encoding="bytes")
    frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow('ImageWindow',frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Did this get solved?

Comment: No it didn't.Here I am trying to create a server and client interface which are seperated from each other by internet.

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST OF ALL**
You have generated the wrong Link for the client to connect to i.e

```
#Tring to connect to the hosted address obtained after using ngrok http 8485 command.
client_socket.connect(('https://fc766cc3.ngrok.io',0))
```

You neeed to use TCP  instead of HTTP when using NGROK . Because the Http is used when you are hosting a web app on your server . so the client can go over to any browser paste your provided link and port and connect to your website.
And you used `port 0` , I maybe wrong but i dont think portzr `0` is useable
and NGROK does not provide you port `0`.
**AND SECOND :**
Even if you do get a TCP link NGROK does not allow Screen sharing over their Free server . You are able to send small messages or files but Screen Sharing is not possible .